# What are role providers?

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, zend-framework2, roles

How do I use zfc rbac role providers?

I understand guards prevent users from accessing routes but it seems like I need the role providers as well.  Are these database permissions?  In the example below is 'article' a controller and the part after the '.' the permission granted on that controller?  How can I test these once in place?  Many thanks.

```
return [
    'zfc_rbac' => [
        'role_provider' => [
            'ZfcRbac\Role\InMemoryRoleProvider' => [
                'admin' => [
                    'permissions' => [
                        'article.delete',
                        'article.edit',
                        'article.archive',
                        'article.read'
                    ]
                ],
                'member' => [
                    'permissions' => [
                        'article.edit',
                        'article.archive',
                        'article.read'
                    ]
                ],
                'guest' => [
                    'permissions' => ['article.read']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here you can read about role providers](https://github.com/Danielss89/ZfcRbac/blob/master/docs/04.%20Role%20providers.md#what-are-role-providers)

In ZF-Rbac one identity can have different roles with different permissions/privileges. To collect the roles for the authorizationService you need role providers. They will include a [`RoleProvicerInterface` (link)](https://github.com/Danielss89/ZfcRbac/blob/master/src/ZfcRbac/Role/RoleProviderInterface.php#L41) with the `getRoles` method which is supposed to return the roles that the authorization service has to work with.

Each Identity has an [`IdentityInterface` (link)](https://github.com/Danielss89/ZfcRbac/blob/master/src/ZfcRbac/Identity/IdentityInterface.php#L33) which has also a `getRoles` method. This will return an array of `roleNames` which will be mapped to the roles from the `RolesProvider` to find out about permissions/privileges.

You can then find out what the current user (identity) is allowed to do.

Comment: I understand the roles and have setup my guard blockers (which is based on user roles I have set up in the DB).  In my current situation each user has one role and I have developed modules for each role type.  It works currently as 'foo role' can not access the 'bar module'.  However when re-reading the documentation it seems like I need role providers as well as guard blockers.  Can you expand on the syntax above?  Is the 'article' a controller or action?

Comment: Or are these basic permissions?  For example if guest has 'article.read' they can only read from the database and cannot write or edit records?

Comment: @Matt I think it is totally up to you whether the permission maps to a controller or action or whatever. In this case I think the example is for a controller of a resource (`article`) and actions inside the controller (`delete`, `edit`, `archive` and `read`).

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on the use of 'article' or how the example code is set up.  Using the album as an example would the below allow the guest users to read the album module? (they would not be allowed to create,save, edit or delete records):                  'guest' => [
                    'permissions' => ['album.read']
                ]

Comment: It does not seem to be working.  When I use  'guest' => [ 'permissions' => ['phone.edit'] ] it does not seem to be doing anything.  I can access the action with or without the code

Comment: I am using the developer tool and can see my role and the permissions but they don't seem t be doing anything.